# How to append a dataframe to an existing Apache Arrow file on disk

Tags: pyarrow

Scenario: In my daily ETL process, I'm considering storing my data additionally as Apache Arrow files for the benefit of zero-copy serialization.

If I have an existing Apache Arrow file on disk with the previous data, how can I use `pyarrow` to append my processed data for the current day(as a dataframe) to the existing arrow file on disk?

I tried using the "a" mode but that didn't work

```py
  with pa.OSFile(output, "a") as sink:
        with pa.RecordBatchFileWriter(sink, table_df.schema) as writer:
            writer.write_table(table_df)
```

- Is this not recommended? Am I violating the design intent of Apache Arrow?
- My other approach would be to read the arrow file as a dataframe, append to it with my current data and then write it back again. But I'm wondering if there is a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow files are immutable once written, you can't append data through existing APIs.  Reading and then writing the data back in would be your only choice if all elements need to be in the same file.

The Arrow Stream format could technically support appending data, but you would lose random access to RecordBatch's